# Error compiling Typescript with graphql files

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, tsc, serverless-framework

So I'm new in this area, the thing is that I'm trying to compile a Typescript project with graphql files on it (with `.graphql`extension).
It' based on the serverless framework, so to compile it I launch `npm start`which launches a `cd src/app && tsc`in the command line.

The `.ts`file references the `.graphql`file like this:

`import SchemaDefinition from './schemaDefinition.graphql';`

And the error is

> data/schema/index.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module './schemaDefinition.graphql'.

I think the issue here is in the `tsc`compilation, as it creates the output directory (../../built) but it is not copying the `.graphql`files. Here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "es6"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "outDir": "../../built",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
            "@types/node",
            "@types/graphql"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
        },
    "include": [
        "./*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
            "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure if I have to do some trick to copy these files or put a precompiler step to convert the `.graphql`files in `.ts`files, using something like this: [GraphQL Code Generator](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator)

Any ideas out there? I'm stuck :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are packaging the banckend in NodeJS, it should be configured in the `webpack.config.js` file and in the `typings.d.ts` files, so both the editor and the packager knows about these files.

`typings.d.ts`:

```
declare module "*.graphql" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

code:

```
import * as query from query.graphql
```

For this to work, a loader such as raw-loader for those using Webpack will work.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
    { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
    { test: /\.graphql$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
  ]
```

This sample has been taken from https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tools/issues/273 where there's an active discussion about different approaches.

Here is a GitHub repo which does roughly the same but with a more powerful solution: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin

On the other hand, if you are packaging the front, there's a handy plugin to do the work for you: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-graphql-loader

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the graphql files have a JS extension so are processed if they do not export anything or nothing imports them you could try the not recommended

import "./my-module.js";

Answer (score -2):

Another workaround is to copy `.graphql` file to the output folder through automated script for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy