# how to use .graphql in a typescript node project without webpack

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have a node, express server using expressGraphql. I am trying to declare a type definition for graphql in a `.graphql` or `.gql` file, because as the type gets larger, it becomes difficult to read the `string`.

**Here is what I have:**

```
import testQuery from './test.graphql';

import routes from "./routes";

import { buildSchema } from "graphql";

const schema = buildSchema(testQuery);

// Root resolver
const root = {
    message: () => "Hello World!",
};

app.use(
    "/api/graphql",
    expressGraphQL({
        schema,
        graphiql: true,
    })
);
```

My graphql file. //test.graphql

```
type Book {
    message: String
}
```

I get an error because Typescript

> Cannot find module './test.graphql'.

I have seen people doing this:

```
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');

const schemaFile = path.join(__dirname, 'schema.graphql');
const typeDefs = fs.readFileSync(schemaFile, 'utf8');

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs });
```

Is this the way of doing it?

So what do I need to to config typescript to be able to import, and build the schema

Comment: Reading the file as pure text, as you mentioned, is the best way to do it if you are not using any bundler (like webpack). This way you also have the benefit to lint and auto-format gql files easier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error compiling Typescript with graphql files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818401/error-compiling-typescript-with-graphql-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there are two ways to import schema files, either 1) by reading the file directly as you describe above, or 2) by wrapping the queries in exported variables.

```
// bookSchema.ts <- note the file extension is .ts instead of .graphql
export default `
  type Book {
    message: String
  }
`

// anotherSchema.ts <- note the file extension is .ts instead of .graphql
export default `
  type User {
    name: String
  }
`

// main.ts
import bookSchema from 'bookSchema';
import anotherSchema from 'anotherSchema';

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: [
  bookSchema,
  anotherSchema,
] });
```

Comment: and is that really the best of doing it? That means i will have to use that methods for every type file I define

Comment: I did not see the error message you posted. Did you remove it again?

Comment: Not sure this is the best way of doing it. I've been going between these two methods over a few apps I've been working on. In my current project I use .graphql files and read them with fs.readFile. It's a matter of preference I'd say. Some devtools are bettter at dealing with plain .graphql text files so that might weight in that direction.

Comment: This is not the answer on how to use .graphql files in typescript without webpack as it suggest to use .ts instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-import-node to solve this without webpack.

Install with `yarn add graphql-import-node` or `npm install --save graphql-import-node` and then either use the `graphql-import-node/register` hook (if you're using ts-node):

`ts-node -r graphql-import-node/register index.ts`

Or import it in your file right at the top like this:

```js
import "graphql-import-node";
```

I chose the later in my case because I already used `ts-node/register` with `mocha -r` for my tests.

You also may need to add `"esModuleInterop": true` to your compilerOptions in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: It was so hard to find this answer, somehow for me `import "graphql-import-node";"`in the index file does not work. But `ts-node -r graphql-import-node/register index.ts` does the trick

Answer (score 0):

This answer addresses the concerns brought up by @leogoesger. 
Its a modular approach of creating schemas using `.graphql` files without needing to define multiple `makeExecutableSchema` calls.

The folder structure should look something like this for it to work:

```
    src
    - graphql
     - schema.ts
     - bar
      - barResolver.ts
      - schema.graphql
     - foo
      - fooResolver.ts
      - schema.graphql
```

`schema.graphql` contains all your type definitions. 
The 'feature' Resolver files contain your resolvers which is an object containing your queries and mutations.

Inside your `schema.ts` file you would create your merged schema like so:

```
    import { mergeSchemas, makeExecutableSchema } from "graphql-tools";
    import { readdirSync, lstatSync, existsSync } from "fs";
    import * as path from "path";
    import { importSchema } from 'graphql-import'
    import { GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';

    const schemas: GraphQLSchema[] = [];

    const isDirectory = dirPath =>  existsSync(dirPath) && lstatSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
    const getDirectories = source =>
      readdirSync(source).map( name => path.join(source, name) ).filter(isDirectory)

    const folders = getDirectories( path.resolve(__dirname, './') )

    folders.forEach(folder => {
        folder = folder.substr( folder.lastIndexOf("\\")+1 )
        const {resolvers} = require(`./${folder}/${folder}Resolver`);
        const typeDefs = importSchema( path.join(__dirname, `./${folder}/schema.graphql`) );
        schemas.push(makeExecutableSchema({resolvers, typeDefs}))
    });

    const mergedSchemas = mergeSchemas({ schemas })

    export default mergedSchemas;
```

The idea is to get all the relative directories that exist on the same level as `schema.ts` then to loop through each feature name and import the respective resolver and type definition. Next we make the schema executable and add it to our schema array. Lastly we stitch the schemas together using `mergeSchemas` to create a single GraphQL schema from multiple API's. (See https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-stitching for more details.)

Then you can create your server as normal

```
import schema from './graphql/schema';
const server = new GraphQLServer({schema: schema})
```