# Can I get "Go to Definition" when I develop an Apollo GraphQL API, with the schema defined in .ts files?

Tags: graphql, apollo

Ok, for 2 years I have been developing a GraphQL Node.js Apollo API in typescript, and there is one thing our team never managed to get up and running: How do we get "Go to Definition" in our `.ts` files, containing the Grahpql Schema?

Our schema is defined in multiple `.ts` files, and it's very frustrating having to look through many files when needing to lookup a type definition, input, etc.

We are all using VS Code, and I hoped I could obtain this with the Apollo Graphql extension. However this only seems to work for client projects?

**Example of code structure**

```
// file 1, inputs.ts
export const inputs = gql`
  input: FancyInput {
     fancyName: String!
  }
`;

// file 2, mutations.ts
export const mutations = gql`
  // HOW do we get "Go to Definition" when right clicking the 'FancyInput'?
  fancyMutation(input: FancyInput): Boolean!
`;

// file 3, apollo-server-setup
const { inputs } = from './inputs';
const { mutations } = from './mutations';
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: [
    inputs,
    mutations
  ]
})
```

In the beginning, this was not a big problem, but now it's super frustrating because the project is rather big today with 30+ schema files.

Comment: reason for using graphql in ts files ? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kumar-harsh.graphql-for-vscode

Comment: Hi xadm - we are just following the graphql apollo server guides, where they are using typescript? Is it possible to define the schema in .gql files?

Comment: sure, with webpack ... or w/o https://stackoverflow.com/a/55737614/6124657 ... google for `"schema.graphql" webpack` or generators/loaders